# Gnome-software is closing automatically after opening it

Tags: gnome, gnome-software

I get the following when trying to run from the terminal:

```
03:15:46:0833 Gs  plugin appstream took 1,4 seconds to do setup
03:15:46:0837 Gs  enabled plugins: fwupd, systemd-updates, ubuntuone, packagekit, packagekit-proxy, packagekit-refresh, packagekit-refine-repos, shell-extensions, packagekit-upgrade, packagekit-local, packagekit-offline, os-release, packagekit-url-to-app, desktop-categories, appstream, hardcoded-blacklist, ubuntu-reviews, packagekit-refine, desktop-menu-path, generic-updates, hardcoded-featured, rewrite-resource, steam, hardcoded-popular, modalias, packagekit-history, snap, provenance, provenance-license, icons, key-colors, key-colors-metadata
03:15:46:0837 Gs  disabled plugins: dummy, dpkg, repos, odrs, epiphany
03:15:47:0839 PK  internal error: failed, but no error code: cancelled-priority
03:15:47:0947 Gs  Only 0 apps for recent list, hiding
[1]    8386 segmentation fault (core dumped)  gnome-software
```

I can't get it to work even after complete purge and reinstalling

Comment: How many RAM do you have? What is your Ubuntu version and desktop?